# Gulp: Copy all files but exclude one extension

Tags: gulp, glob

I'm working on a Typescript project, and I am trying to implement Gulp.
In my `src/` folder, I have files with different extensions.

I've configured Gulp to transpile every `*.ts` file to Javascript using Babel, and to output the type-definition files using the Typescript compiler.
I would like all other files to be copied to the `dist/` folder.

```
const {
  dest,
  src
} = require("gulp");

function cp() {
  return src("src/**/*.*", "!(src/**/*.ts)")
    .pipe(dest("./dist"));
};

exports.cp = cp;
```

I would like the `cp` function to copy every file except those with a `.ts` extension to the `dist/` folder.

The above code works if I define the extensions that I want to copy and avoid using the wildcard extension.
I've found many examples online, but they are usually not using a wildcard extension. I'm not sure if the problem comes from my negation or from the usage of a wildcard extension. Is there any way to do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

The solution was written black on white in the official documentation of the src() method. Here is the fix:

```
const {
  dest,
  src
} = require("gulp");

function cp() {
  return src(["src/**/*.*", "!src/**/*.ts"])
    .pipe(dest("./dist"));
};

exports.cp = cp;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
"!src/**/*.ts"
```

Remove the enclosing parentheses that you had `"!(src/**/*.ts)"`.

Comment: No, its the same result with and without parenthesis :(

Comment: Ahh, so I caught one of the mistakes but not the other.